# Why does a thermocouple circuit need to have minimal current flowing through it?

Tags: thermocouple

I was reading on [this website](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-9/thermocouples/) that

> it is imperative that current in a thermocouple circuit be kept as low as possible for good measurement accuracy

Why is this the case?

Also, if one makes it so there is very little resistance through the thermocouple circuit (and hence less voltage drop inaccuracies), then wouldn't this cause the current flowing through the circuit to be high by nature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have picked out a quote from the very end of the article, where they are adding *swamping resistors* to average multiple thermocouples. This is a very unusual and error-prone technique, not one for the amateur. If the resistors are too large, then voltage drop in the resistors, due to bias current flowing in the amplifier input, will lead to very large errors.

A better quotation to take is from earlier in that article ...

> For measurement purposes, the voltmeter used in a thermocouple circuit is designed to have a very high resistance so as to avoid any error-inducing voltage drops along the thermocouple wire. The problem of voltage drop along the conductor length is even more severe here than with the DC voltage signals discussed earlier, because here we only have a few millivolts of voltage produced by the junction. We simply cannot afford to have even a single millivolt of drop along the conductor lengths without incurring serious temperature measurement errors.

Measurement thermocouple wires are, by their nature, relatively high resistance. The materials are high resistance (nichrome) and the wires tend to be thin, and can be very long, especially in remote temperature measurement, 10s of ohms is common. With a sensitivity of 10s of \$\mu V\$ per degree C, currents in the order of \$\mu A\$ will cause degrees of error.

We don't need to be passing \$\mu A\$ through a thermocouple when measuring it. Even back in the day when a moving mirror meter required many times this current, they used bridge balance circuits to measure with zero bias current through the thermocouple. These days, any 10 cent 'cooking grade' amplifier will have a bias current in the nA.

A thing to watch for is when using thermocouple interface ICs. They will often have a 'broken thermocouple detect' current source to inject into the thermocouple circuit to test whether there is DC continuity, a high voltage reading indicates the wires are broken. If this current source is accidentally left on during measurement, it can cause a severe error.

If we do keep the thermocouple circuit resistance low, as in the 'flame failure' solenoid circuit of gas fires and gas hobs, then large currents can indeed flow. A single themocouple is connected to a very low voltage high current coil, and many amps flow to hold in the gas valve, once the flame is heating the business end of the thermocouple.

Comment: Toi clarify why "thermocouples can be very long" above: There are always two thermocouples, and you only ever measure the difference between them. Thermocouples do not give actual temperature. One is the hot junction, the other is wherever the thermocouple wire meets copper wire again (the cold junction). To know actual temperature you have to measure the cold junction temperature (with a thermistor) When you extend the thermocouple, the extension cable and all connectors are the same 2 materials as the thermocouple, right up to the cold junction where the thermistor is.

Comment: But if we did have a large current flowing through the circuit generated by the thermocouple, then why would that affect the accuracy of the reading? All it would mean is that either our resistance is extremely low across the thermocouple wire or there is a large voltage coming from the thermocouple.

Comment: @AmolGarg Because if a large current is flowing, that means the voltmeter resistance is low, and is comparable to the thermocouple resistance, which means there is an appreciable difference in voltage between the thermocouple junction output, and the voltage at the meter. That difference is an error.

Answer (score 4):

Thermocouples generate a small signal voltage on the order of 50 μV/°C. (Notice that it's *micro* volts.)  The thermocouple wires aren't ideal conductors, so they have resistance.  If you have current flowing through the thermocouple, it will cause a voltage drop due to resistance in the thermocouple wires.  This voltage drop will appear on top of the thermocouple signal, and it will be indistinguishable from the thermocouple signal.

Answer (score 2):

There are exceptions to the low-current rule.

Some thermocouple circuits cycle through application
of a high current to keep the wiring junctions from losing conductivity, essentially burning through minor metal oxidation.

Other thermocouple circuits employ a small current to test for
continuity (against broken wires or bad contacts).

Still other circuits use the thermocouple wiring as an
auxiliary heater, and only turn off the heating currents
for short periods to monitor temperature.

No significant current is needed or wanted
during a measurement with modern electronics.   The
wire resistance, times the at-measurement-time current, is
an error term (and wire resistance is not well controlled,
especially in thermocouples for furnace or corrosive environments).
So, it makes sense to minimize currents during a measurement to minimize that error term.

Answer (score 1):

You want all the voltage to make it to the receiving end.

The parasitic resistance in the thermocouple wires forms a basic voltage divider with the impedance of the amplifier that's used to gain the thermocouple's tiny voltage output (tens of mV, tops) up to something usable (such as a few volts for a full-scale output).  In order to minimize the voltage drop (which causes an error, because the dropped voltage doesn't make it to the amplifier terminals, and thus throws off the reading as the amplifier sees less voltage = lower temperature), the parasitic resistance needs to be as small as possible, and the amplifier input impedance needs to be as large as possible.

Hence, thermocouple wires are often reasonably thick, with a resistance on the order of less than 10 ohms, and the amplifier has an extremely high input impedance (on the order of 10 megohms or more).  As a result of this high input impedance on the amplifier, basically no current (microamps or less) flows through the circuit.